# Parallel processing in Foreach loop

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hello I have a situation where I am calling some API to get a list of movies. For each record in the list, I call another API. I would like to make that `for` loop parallel for better performance. The following is my sample code.

```
movies = []

for movie in collection:
    tmdb_movie = tmdb.get_movie(movie['detail']['ids']['tmdb_id'])
    movies.append(tmdb_movie)

return tmdb_movie
```

So my solution using multiprocessing is as follows:

```
pool = Pool()
output = pool.map(tmdb.get_movie, [movie['detail']['ids']['tmdb_id'] for movie in collection])
```

But when I execute this code, I get following error

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed
```

I would really appreciate if someone can help me making this functionality parallel in python 2.7.

Comment: We don't implement features, we help with errors and other issues in existing code. There's a [library](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html) to make stuff parallel.

Comment: Do you have to use Python 2.7? It's better to use the asyncio module for I/O bound tasks like this but it's only available in Python 3.5+

Comment: Yes my problem is I am limited to Python 2.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best option for this would be to use threads. Threads in Python cannot use CPUs in parallel, but they can execute concurrently while there are blocking operations. Processes, although the can really run in parallel, are slow to start and communicate with, and are better suited to big CPU-bounded work loads. Also, as you indicate in your question, processes can sometimes be difficult to launch.

You can use the somewhat-secret (i.e. undocumented but actually well known) `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` class. If you are going to be doing this many times, you can create a pool once at the beginning and reuse it. You just need to make sure `pool.close()` and maybe also `pool.join()` are called when the program exits.

```
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

# Global/class variables    
NUM_THREADS = 5
pool = ThreadPool(NUM_THREADS)

# Inside some function/method
return pool.map(lambda movie: tmdb.get_movie(movie['detail']['ids']['tmdb_id']), movies)

# On exit
pool.close()  # Prevents more jobs to be submitted
pool.join()  # Waits until all jobs are finished
```

Comment: Thanks very much. Does this pool.map function respects the initial sorting/sequence of collection? (movies collection in my example)

Comment: @nafr1 Yes, it should give you the mapped sequence in the original order.

Answer (score 2):

You question is very broad and leaves out many of details, so here's a outline of what would need to be done. To avoid the `PicklingError`, the database is opened in each process — which can be done by using an *`initializer`* function (named `start_process()` in the example code below).

Note: Due the the overhead involved in initializing the database to do one query, @jdehesa's multi-threading approach would likely be the better tactic in this situation (threading generally makes sharing a global variable less costly). Alternatively, you could make the `get_movie()` interface function process more than one `id` each time it's called (i.e. "batches" of them).

```
class Database:
    """ Mock implementation. """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass  # Open/connect to database.

    def get_movie(self, id):
        return 'id_%s_foobar' % id


import multiprocessing as mp

def start_process(*args):
    global tmdb
    tmdb = Database(*args)

def get_movie(id):
    tmdb_movie = tmdb.get_movie(id)
    return tmdb_movie

if __name__ == '__main__':

    collection = [{'detail': {'ids': {'tmdb_id': 1}}},
                  {'detail': {'ids': {'tmdb_id': 2}}},
                  {'detail': {'ids': {'tmdb_id': 3}}}]

    pool_size = mp.cpu_count()
    with mp.Pool(processes=pool_size, initializer=start_process,
                 initargs=('init info',)) as pool:
        movies = pool.map(get_movie, (movie['detail']['ids']['tmdb_id']
                                        for movie in collection))

    print(movies)  # -> ['id_1_foobar', 'id_2_foobar', 'id_3_foobar']
```

An multiprocessing alternative which would allow the database to be shared to some degree by multiple processes without connecting to it each time, would be to define a custom [`multiprocessing.Manager()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#managers) that opened the database once, and provided an interface to it to get the info for one (or more movies) given their id(s). This is also discussed in the [Sharing state between processes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) section (in the **Server Process** subsection) of the online documentation. The built-in `Manager` supports a number of container types, `list`s, `dict`s, and `Queue`s.

Below is example code showing how to create your own custom manager for the database. If you uncomment the calls to `print()`, you'll see that only one `Database` instance is created:

```
class Database:
    """ Mock implementation. """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
#        print('Database.__init__')
        pass  # Open/connect to database.

    def get_movie(self, id):
        return 'id_%s_foobar' % id


from functools import partial
import multiprocessing as mp
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager


class DB_Proxy(object):
    """ Shared Database instance proxy class. """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.database = Database(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_movie(self, id):
#        print('DB_Proxy.get_movie')
        tmdb_movie = self.database.get_movie(id)
        return tmdb_movie


class MyManager(BaseManager): pass  # Custom Manager

MyManager.register('DB_Proxy', DB_Proxy)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    collection = [{'detail': {'ids': {'tmdb_id': 1}}},
                  {'detail': {'ids': {'tmdb_id': 2}}},
                  {'detail': {'ids': {'tmdb_id': 3}}}]

    manager = MyManager()
    manager.start()

    db_proxy = manager.DB_Proxy('init info')

    pool_size = mp.cpu_count()
    with mp.Pool(pool_size) as pool:
        movies = pool.map(db_proxy.get_movie,
                          (movie['detail']['ids']['tmdb_id']
                            for movie in collection))

    print(movies)  # -> ['id_1_foobar', 'id_2_foobar', 'id_3_foobar']
```

Comment: Thank you very much for response. I ended up using ThreadPool from multiprocessing.pool and it worked perfectly fine on Windows. However, I am targeting my application for Android and I guess multiprocessing is not supported on Android. Any other solution you can think of? Maybe directly using  threading.Thread?

Comment: Sorry I don't know much about Android. Regardless, threads can be used without a `ThreadPool`, which according to its docstring is a "Class which supports an async version of applying functions to arguments" and is derived from `multipprocessing.Pool`. Anyway, yes, it's likely possible for you to use `threading.Thread` directly. You could use a `Queue.Queue` to communicate between the main thread and a background thread that continuously takes things from an input `Queue`, looks them up, and puts the results obtained into an output `Queue`, which can then be retrieved by the main thread.